# Как реализовать Header и Footer в HTML файле. Чтобы каждый раз не переделывать к примеру footer хочу подключать его со стороннего .html файла

Tags: html, html5

HTML. Как реализовать Header и Footer в HTML файле. Сайт написан на HTML. Перелиновка и прочие переходы сделаны вручную. Чтобы каждый раз не переделывать footer на каждой странице хочу подключать его со стороннего .html файла и встраивать внутрь того же html. Есть ли варианты?

Ещё, если не лень, подскажите как правильно делаются подобные многостраничные сайты? Вряд ли так мудохаются) Это уж я пока учусь, ищу варианты, узнаю. Если не сложно объясните суть. Может посоветуете что почитать, что изучить. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

используйте pug :)

Ну или можете посмотреть здесь https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Из примера следует

```
<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>

<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /* Loop through a collection of all HTML elements: */
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /* Make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name: */
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /* Remove the attribute, and call this function once more: */
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /* Exit the function: */
      return;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

То есть, вы можете подключать файлы с помощью js скрипта

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл вариант проще. Мне как новичку сложно и не хочется использовать замысловатые коды.
Я воспользовался таким вариантом:

```
    <!--#include file="./footer.html" -->
```

Если правильно понимаю, то в этом месте в любом документе где вставляю, появляется кусочек кода из footer.html / И всё это обрабатывается сервером. Так намного проще я считаю, чем городить js код) Главное работает, проверено)